# How do I set up a subdomain to point to a subfolder in VUE and Typescript App hosted on Heroku + domain on Route 53?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, subdomain

So I have a VUE and Typescript app with NPM serve hosted on Heroku with the domain on AWS Route53 https://www.codelion.ai/ which starts on a landing page. There are two bouncing buttons and one takes you to https://www.codelion.ai/play and the other to https://www.codelion.ai/learn. I would like all the content from https://www.codelion.ai/play to go to https://play.codelion.ai/, e.g. https://www.codelion.ai/play/profile/settings would become https://play.codelion.ai/profile/settings. Same for the Learn part, I'd like it to go to https://learn.codelion.ai/. Files are in separate folders, there are separate routers for Learn and Play part. Original domain and subdomains are connected so visiting https://play.codelion.ai/ or https://learn.codelion.ai/ does the same thing as visiting https://www.codelion.ai/. I tried creating another reverse-proxy app but that collides with CORS settings and it just doesn't work. ChatGPT also gave up after a day of asking the same question, comes back with weird responses. What can I do? Thanks

Edit: I'm using Vite too